# Auquel comme adjectif

Tags: adjectifs

Je pense que je comprends comment utiliser auquel (à laquelle, auxquels, auxquelles) quand on l'utilise pour remplacer un nom  par un pronom.

> J'ai beaucoup de jeux, auxquels voulez-vous jouer ?

Mais je désire savoir aussi comment l'utiliser comme adjectif interrogatif. Et là je ne sais pas du tout me débrouiller.

Par exemple, puis-je dire *Auxquels jeux jouez-vous ?*

*À + lesquels* = *auxquels* non ? Mais ce terme-là a l'air si bizarre que je crois  faire erreur. J'ai peur qu'on ne puisse pas utiliser « *auxquels* » comme adjectif mais je ne sais pas comment construire la phrase sans l'utiliser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans ce cas, il faut utiliser la forme "À + quel".

> À quels jeux jouez-vous ?

Pour t'aider à mémoriser cette construction, tu peux poser la phrase à l'affirmative : "Je joue ***à*** des jeux".

Si vous permettez, j'aimerais aussi rectifier quelques petites erreurs dans votre commentaire :

> Peux-je dire [...] -> Puis-je dire [...]
>
> J'ai peur que je fais des bêtises -> J'ai peur de faire des bêtises
>
> J'ai peur qu'on peut pas utiliser -> J'ai peur qu'on ne puisse pas utiliser
>
> Merci pour m'aider -> Merci de m'aider *ou* Merci de votre aide

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Je faisais des contractions là ou je n'en avais pas besoin je pense.